# How can I set the value of a JQuery slider based on a form submitted input field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Started looking at the [API for the slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider/slider#.22value.22value), getting a little confused. I have a simple form, with one input, feeding into a "results" page that contains a slider. When the user slides the slider handle, the value changes (meaning the final value is computed in a function - input is added to a number)

Right now, I have the value of the slider hard coded, but I'd like the value to be the actual value from the original forms input. Not sure how to get that done, but here's the function I am working with:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ds1").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        step: 7,
        range: "min",
        max: 200,
        value: 50,
        slide: refreshTotal,
        change: refreshTotal
    });
});
```

So the value is hard coded to 50, but I'd like an input field to control that value. The refreshTotal function handles the actual computation. It would be great to also set the max value too if that is handled the same way as this.

I've searched on here and found a few examples of "real time" input's affecting the slider, and visa versa using keyup, etc. But I can't figure out how to set the value (perhaps using a getter), based on the form input field after the user hits submit, and JQuery handles the computation.

I think this is a pretty simple thing, just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Looks like I can set the value to 0, as the default, then take the user input and set the .value() from that input. Looking into this a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes jQuery & jQuery UI.

```
$(function () {
    var $slider = $('#slider').slider();
    var $input_a = $('#input_a');

    // Set slider value
    $input_a.on('keyup', function () {
        $slider.value($(this).val());

    // Default slider
    }).trigger('keyup');

    // Set input value
    $slider.change(function () {
        $input_a.val($(this).value());
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you've gotten the value of the input field from the original form.  Since you didn't mention a backend language, some sample code of how to do that in PHP would look like:

```
<? $value = $_POST['slider_value']; ?>
var slider_value = <? echo $value; ?>;
```

Then, you can use the selector in the API Docs you mentioned:

```
$( "#ds1" ).slider( "option", "value", slider_value);
```

You can handle the maximum value of the slider in a similar manner:

```
$( "#ds1" ).slider( "option", "max", insert_number_here);
```

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning that. This is PHP on the back end. I have the value getting set to a variable in PHP like you have posted. Can you echo out the value in a variable crossing PHP with JS? I see you are then setting the value of the function, which makes sense.

Comment: Yes, since PHP is backend and JavaScript is client-side, you can set JavaScript variables to the value of PHP variables in the way I showed above.  Try a simple example.